# SQL to Isolate records from updating data meeting criteria

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with following columns:
Account,Indicator,StartDate,EndDate
Indicator changes every so often (randomly) from N to Y.
When indicator updates start date changes so does end date.
Start date and end date can change because of changes in other flags on this table so Indicator might not have updated, but start and end date will have done.

I'm trying to isolate all Account records using SQL where the indicator has gone from Y to N in the life of the account, as this should never happen

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'm struggling to see that you could do that with a query.  Perhaps you could add a trigger which adds rows to an archive table so you could then query that comparing to the current values?  Or else consider constraints to stop this from happening?

Comment: I don't get what you want, can you add some example rows and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is peak ahead to the next record to see if the indicator changed. If you are trying to isolate the case where only the indicator changed, you will need to expand the comparison to included every other attribute that may have changed on the record. If your table is substantially large, running this against the table in its entirety may chew through resources.

Since I didn't have sample data to test with, the SQL I am providing is written in the spirit of what you are trying to accomplish. `ColA` and `ColB` represent your primary key, or whatever uniquely identifies a record in your table. The windowing functions are used to look ahead one row so you can compare the current record's value for `Indicator` to the next record's value of `Indicator`:

```
SELECT ColA
     , ColB
     , Indicator
     , StartDate
     , EndDate
     , MAX(Indicator) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB 
                            ORDER BY StartDate 
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS NextIndicator
     , MAX(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB 
                            ORDER BY StartDate 
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS NextStartDate
     , MAX(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB 
                            ORDER BY StartDate 
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS NextEndDate
  FROM MyTable
QUALIFY NextIndicator <> Indicator;
```